# What pairs well with cannabis wine?

Tags: wine, ingredients, pairing

**What pairs well with cannabis wine?**

> [**Cannabis Wine**](https://winefolly.com/lifestyle/rainbow-wine-is-green-wine-really-wine/): Herbs have been infused into wine since the time of ancient Greece. These aromatized wines are now even being infused with cannabis. One such product, Know Label, uses various strains of cannabis that are cold-extracted into the wine during vinification. The final product cannot legally be called wine, and is labeled as a “wine tincture” instead (it has 12% ABV and 3% THC). As for the color, these wines resemble standard red and white wines.

PS. Up here in Canada, marijuana is quite legal!